# Proper way to handle SIGTERM with multiple threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, posix, raspbian

I have a multi threaded program on Raspberry in which I want to handle SIGTERM and shut everything down gracefully. The issue is that I have a background thread that has called `recvfrom()` on a blocking socket. As per my understanding from the man pages, if I exit my handler all the system calls should be woken up and return with -1 and `errno` set to `EINTR`. However in my case the `recvfrom` call keeps hanging.

1) In general am I understanding this right, that all threads that have blocking system calls that are able to be woken up by a signal should wake up in this scenario?
2) Could it be that the operating system is setting some special signal mask on my thead?

The interresting part is that I am using the VideoCore primitives, not pthread, maybe that could be the cause? Here is a small test example:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>


#include "interface/vcos/vcos.h"

void SignalHandler(int nSignalNumber)
{
    std::cout << "received signal " << nSignalNumber << std::endl;
}

void* ThreadMain(void* pArgument)
{
    int nSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (nSocket >= 0)
    {
        sockaddr_in LocalAddress;
        memset(&LocalAddress, 0, sizeof(LocalAddress));
        LocalAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
        LocalAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
        LocalAddress.sin_port = htons(1234);
        if (bind(nSocket, reinterpret_cast<sockaddr *>(&LocalAddress), sizeof(LocalAddress)) == 0)
        {
            sockaddr_in SenderAddress;
            socklen_t nSenderAddressSize = sizeof(SenderAddress);
            unsigned char pBuffer[512];
            std::cout << "calling recvfrom()" << std::endl;
            int nBytesReceived = recvfrom(nSocket, pBuffer, sizeof(pBuffer), 0, reinterpret_cast<struct sockaddr *>(&SenderAddress), &nSenderAddressSize);
            if (nBytesReceived == -1)
            {
                if (errno == EINTR)
                {
                    std::cout << "recvfrom() was interrupred by a signal" << std::endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    std::cout << "recvfrom() failed with " << errno << std::endl;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "bind() failed with " << errno << std::endl;
        }
        close(nSocket);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "socket() failed with " << errno << std::endl;
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    struct sigaction SignalAction;
    memset(&SignalAction, 0, sizeof(SignalAction));
    SignalAction.sa_handler = SignalHandler;
    sigaction(SIGTERM, &SignalAction, NULL);
    VCOS_THREAD_T Thread;
    VCOS_STATUS_T nVcosStatus = vcos_thread_create(&Thread, "", NULL, ThreadMain, NULL);
    if (nVcosStatus == VCOS_SUCCESS)
    {
        void* pData = NULL;
        vcos_thread_join(&Thread, &pData);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "vcos_thread_create() failed with " << nVcosStatus << std::endl;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

It can be compiled like this:

```
g++ test.cpp -I/opt/vc/include -L/opt/vc/lib -lvcos  -o test
```

When I run it and then call `kill` on the running instance the output is:

```
calling recvfrom()
received signal 15
```

and the process hangs. I'll try if a pthread behaves differently.

**UPDATE**

Ok I updated the sample to spawn a pthread thread as well and that one is not quitting as well. So I assume the signals are not populated to all threads?

```
#include <iostream>

#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#include "interface/vcos/vcos.h"

void SignalHandler(int nSignalNumber)
{
    std::cout << "received signal " << nSignalNumber << std::endl;
}

void* ThreadMain(void* pArgument)
{
    const char* pThreadType = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(pArgument);
    int nSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (nSocket >= 0)
    {
        sockaddr_in LocalAddress;
        memset(&LocalAddress, 0, sizeof(LocalAddress));
        LocalAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
        LocalAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
        LocalAddress.sin_port = htons(pThreadType[0] * 100);
        if (bind(nSocket, reinterpret_cast<sockaddr *>(&LocalAddress), sizeof(LocalAddress)) == 0)
        {
            sockaddr_in SenderAddress;
            socklen_t nSenderAddressSize = sizeof(SenderAddress);
            unsigned char pBuffer[512];
            std::cout << "calling recvfrom()" << std::endl;
            int nBytesReceived = recvfrom(nSocket, pBuffer, sizeof(pBuffer), 0, reinterpret_cast<struct sockaddr *>(&SenderAddress), &nSenderAddressSize);
            if (nBytesReceived == -1)
            {
                if (errno == EINTR)
                {
                    std::cout << "recvfrom() was interrupred by a signal" << std::endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    std::cout << "recvfrom() failed with " << errno << std::endl;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "bind() failed with " << errno << std::endl;
        }
        close(nSocket);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "socket() failed with " << errno << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << pThreadType << " thread is exiting" << std::endl;
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    struct sigaction SignalAction;
    memset(&SignalAction, 0, sizeof(SignalAction));
    SignalAction.sa_handler = SignalHandler;
    sigaction(SIGTERM, &SignalAction, NULL);
    VCOS_THREAD_T VcosThread;
    VCOS_STATUS_T nVcosStatus = vcos_thread_create(&VcosThread, "", NULL, ThreadMain, const_cast<char*>("vcos"));
    bool bJoinVcosThread = false;
    if (nVcosStatus == VCOS_SUCCESS)
    {
        bJoinVcosThread = true;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "vcos_thread_create() failed with " << nVcosStatus << std::endl;
    }
    pthread_t PthreadThread;
    int nPthreadStatus = pthread_create(&PthreadThread, NULL, ThreadMain, const_cast<char*>("pthread"));
    bool bJoinPthreadThread = false;
    if (nPthreadStatus == 0)
    {
        bJoinPthreadThread = true;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "pthread_create() failed with " << nPthreadStatus << std::endl;
    }
    if (bJoinVcosThread)
    {
        void* pData = NULL;
        vcos_thread_join(&VcosThread, &pData);
    }
    if (bJoinPthreadThread)
    {
        void* pData = NULL;
        pthread_join(PthreadThread, &pData);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A signal such as `SIGTERM` is submitted to one thread in the process only.  The only precondition is that the chosen thread must either have not masked the signal, or must wait for it using `sigwait`.  The other threads will not be directly notified that the signal has been delivered.

A common approach to combine signals with threads is to have a separate thread which handles signals only and notifies the other threads using thread synchronization mechanisms such as condition variables.

For interrupting file I/O, this may not be sufficient because there is a race condition between checking for a termination request and making the system call to perform the I/O operation.  Some language run-time libraries use non-blocking I/O with `poll` or `epoll` with a special file descriptor which becomes ready on signal delivery (either using the previously-mentioned thread-based approach, or something Linux-specific like `signalfd`).  Others try to avoid this overhead by using the `read` and `write` system calls directly with a complicated dance which uses `dup2` to replace the file descriptor with one that always causes I/O to fail, thereby avoiding the race condition (but the bookkeeping needed for that is fairly complicated).

Comment: Thanks, this addressed my main question. I am aware of `eventfd` and `signalfd` but since I am using the vcos event primitives to stop my thread I can't mix them with socket in a `poll` or `epoll`. I'll just stick with a `select` with a reasonable \timeout and after that check my vcos termination primitive if the socket did not have any I/O events.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch that is a valid approach, but I already have a vcos event for my thread class which is set when someone tries to stop the thread. Adding a pipe would again require more code than a simple `select` with a timeout. But I upvoted your answer as well.

Answer (score 3):

The [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/7/signal) for `signal` reads:

> If a signal handler is invoked while a system call or library function call is blocked, then either:
>
> - the call is automatically restarted after the signal handler returns; or
> - the call fails with the error EINTR.
>
> Which of these two behaviors occurs depends on the interface and whether or not the signal handler was established using the SA_RESTART flag (see sigaction(2)). The details vary across UNIX systems<...>

A few lines below, `recvfrom` is listed among the functions that use `SA_RESTART` behavior by default. (Note: this behavior is disabled if there's a timeout on the socket, though.)

Thus, you should fill the `sa_flags` field of the `sigaction` structure to carefully **avoid** setting the `SA_RESTART` flag.

Comment: As you see I do a `memset` on the sigaction structure so the `SA_RESTART` field is not set.

Answer (score 2):

A good way to deal with blocking sockets -see [socket(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html)- (and even non blocking ones) is to use a multiplexing syscall like [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) (or the obsolete [select(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html)....)

Regarding signals, be sure to read [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) and [signal-safety(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html).

A common way to handle signals with some [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) (using [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)) is to have a signal handler which simply [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html)-s a byte on a [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) to self (you'll setup the pipe at initialization, and you'll poll it in your event loop). The Qt documentation explains [how and why](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/unix-signals.html). You might also use the Linux specific [signalfd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html).

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of `eventfd`, but since the vcos primitives provided by Broadcomm had some other nice things as event flags, I made everything based on their primitives and now rewriting everything to clean POSIX would be a big effort.